# Show the Pos User only the Contacts she has created | Odoo - models.JS

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, erp, odoo-14

Odoo 14 is an open source erp system. I want to customize the Point of Sale module but as a rookie I couldn't do it.

Odoo uploads and presents all customers to all pos users. I want to fetch only contacts created by POS users, not all customers.

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/point_of_sale/static/src/js/models.js#L221

```
        model:  'res.partner',
    label: 'load_partners',
    fields: ['name','street','city','state_id','country_id','vat','lang',
             'phone','zip','mobile','email','barcode','write_date',
             'property_account_position_id','property_product_pricelist'],
    loaded: function(self,partners){
        self.partners = partners;
        self.db.add_partners(partners);
```

I added one line as domain filter..

```
    model:  'res.partner',
    label: 'load_partners',
    fields: ['name','street','city','state_id','country_id','vat','lang',
             'phone','zip','mobile','email','barcode','write_date',
             'property_account_position_id','property_product_pricelist'],
    **domain: function(){ return [['create_uid', '=', 'pos_session.id']]; },**
    loaded: function(self,partners){
        self.partners = partners;
        self.db.add_partners(partners);
```

But doesn't work.

domain: function(){ return [['create_uid', '=', 2]]; } or 3,4,5 is working.The pos user with the 2,3,4 id number can see the customers she has created.. I don't know how to get the id of the pos user..I would be glad if you help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `"pos.session.id"` or `"pos.session.user_id"` instead of `"pos_session.id"`?

if it doesn't work try replacing the string with `self.session.id` or `self.session.user_id`

I hope this would solve the issue.

I think the code may be like this:

```
{
    model: 'res.partner',
    label: 'load_partners',
    domain: function(){ return [['create_uid', '=', self.session.id]]; }
    fields: ['name','street','city','state_id','country_id','vat','lang',
             'phone','zip','mobile','email','barcode','write_date',
             'property_account_position_id','property_product_pricelist'],
    loaded: function(self,partners){
        self.partners = partners;
        self.db.add_partners(partners);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [session.uid](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/point_of_sale/static/src/js/models.js#L342).

***Example:***

```js
domain: function(self){ return [['create_uid', '=', self.session.uid]]; },
```